# SpecFlow Given and When Scope Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, specflow

I am executing the following test written using SpecFlow framework and when the test reaches "Then" the _accountController is null. Why?

```
 [Binding]
    public class RegisterUserSteps
    {
        private AccountController _accountController;
        private ActionResult _result; 

        [When(@"the user goes to the register user screen")]
        public void WhenTheUserGoesToTheRegisterUserScreen()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("When");

            _accountController = new AccountController();
           _result = _accountController.Register();

        }

        [Then(@"the register user view should be displayed")]
        public void ThenTheRegisterUserViewShouldBeDisplayed()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Then");

            Assert.AreEqual("Register", _accountController.ViewData["Title"]);
        }
    }
```

UPDATE 1:

```
[Binding]
    public class RegisterUserSteps
    {
        private AccountController _accountController = new AccountController();
        private ActionResult _result; 



        [When(@"the user goes to the register user screen")]
        public void WhenTheUserGoesToTheRegisterUserScreen()
        {
           _result = _accountController.Register();
        }

        [Then(@"the register user view should be displayed")]
        public void ThenTheRegisterUserViewShouldBeDisplayed()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual("Register", _accountController.ViewData["Title"]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: At first glance I can't find anything wrong... What happens if you move `_accountController = new AccountController();` into a `[Given()]` method?
`

Comment: For some reason the _accountController is null inside the ThenTheRegisterUserViewShouldBeDisplayed method. There is no Given method for this story.

Comment: I understand there is no Given, but does the strange behavior disappear if you add a Given and move the newing up of `AccountController` to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does making the `_accountController` static resolve the issue? Or newing it up right from the beginning like this?

```
private AccountController _accountController = new AccountController();
```

Comment: Yes that does retain the AccountController. Thanks!

Comment: i can see how it would make it work making it static, but that shouldn't be necessary.  specflow will use the same instance, so the instance members should remain intact.  there is something more to this situation than what is being related in the question.  i used that code and do not see the problem, even without the static.